# What part that control coin's total supply and give initial coins to specific wallet?

Tags: cryptography

As title,

1. Max coins supply.

From github's bitcoin source, where is line or function that define coin's total supply? Like bitcoin's case, 21,000,000. 
I found that amount.h  file has above number, so then revise this number only and all done? What is maximum number this can be? int's max value, 2,100,000,000?

2. Give initial coin.
   How to give initial coin to developer, marketing team member? And to pre-sale ICO customers? Where is that code?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably not find the number 21,000,000 in the source code. The reason is that there are not really 21,000,000 BTC. It's a bit less. You need to sum up the block rewards. It's `210,000 * 50 + 210,000 * 25 + 210,000 * 12.5 ... < 21,000,000`